# Switch between tab navigation and list navigation

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and applying [this pattern](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html) for the tab navigation that I found on android developer site. It's working pretty good but I also want to able to switch between `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` and `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` preserving the association between tabs and the fragments.

The pattern I mentioned above is pretty good for preserving a generic code. So I add listeners to my tabs and associate them with specific fragments like this:

```
bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
.setText("MyFragment")
.setTabListener(new TabListener<SomeFragment>(this, "myfargment", SomeFragment.class)));
```

and instantiate the fragment when the associated tab is clicked with the help of generics:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
}
```

**My question is** how can I achieve a similar way while **navigating between my fragments** with the **list navigation** mode. I couldn't find a similar way since the `OnNavigationListener` for the list on the ActionBar works for the **whole list** instead of **per item basis** like the tablistener.

or do I have to do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    switch (itemPosition) {
    case 0:
    //Replace the current fragment with FragmentA
        break;
    case 1:
    //Replace the current fragment with FragmentB
        break;
    case 2:
    //Replace the current fragment with FragmentC
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have noticed an interesting behaviour:
While the **navigation mode** is set to `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` if I put my phone in **landscape** mode it converts the tabs to a list and **preservers the association** between the fragments and the list items(**which were tab items before**) how can I achieve this result **on demand** rather than **on orientation change**?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible if you are in tab mode to manually set to a list navigation. I have the list navigation set for one of my applications when it falls below the "Large" bucket. This is how I am using the navigation listener:

```
OnNavigationListener mNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener()
{
int mLastPosition = -1;

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId)
{
    String selectedTag = mFragmentNames.get(itemPosition);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(selectedTag);
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    /** Used to avoid the same fragment being reattached. */
    if(mLastPosition != itemPosition)
    {
    /** Means there was a previous fragment attached. */
    if(mLastPosition != -1)
    {
        Fragment lastFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(mFragmentNames.get(mLastPosition));
        if(lastFragment != null)
        ft.remove(lastFragment);
    }

    if(fragment == null)
    {
        /** The fragment is being added for the first time. */
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(HomeActivity.this, selectedTag);
        ft.add(R.id.rootLayout, fragment, selectedTag);
        ft.commit();
    } else
    {
        ft.attach(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    }
    /**
     * The newly attached fragment will be the last position if changed.
     */
    mLastPosition = itemPosition;

    return true;
}
};
```

The variable mFragmentNames is a HashMap that maps a integer position to a fragment name  ex. "com.android.myproject.MyFragment"

I hope this helps.